# While booting it shows error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found. Entering rescue mode... How to tackle this problem?

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I'll be honest I'm a noob in coding and all such things related to it. Please be as specific as possible

My device is a 64-bit device and I've never encrypted anything as such.

Comment: That often is trying to boot in wrong boot mode. Or you have UEFI install, and changed to BIOS install. Often because an old version of BIOS boot grub is still on system. Or vice-versa with BIOS boot install & change to UEFI boot. Check boot mode in UEFI settings. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Given you've provided no OS & release details; you do mention 64-bit, but not if your device is *arm64*, *ppc64el*, *riscv64*, *amd64* or something else, we need to be specific (*i386 implies amd64 but it's best if we're told*). Your error message would imply to me an attempt to boot was made in *legacy* (BIOS) mode as @oldfred alluded to , but we're limited to being *generic* given we don't know anything about what you were running

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.